# Prove a CFG is ambiguous

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need to prove this context free grammar ambiguous, I know to prove this I need to find 2 different paths of the same string, but this question has 'begin' and 'end' which I don't know what they mean

S -> begin A end

A -> A ; A | a | S

Comment: I guess "begin" and "end" are just some terminals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Let $B \to B\ \,;\ B \mid \mathtt{b}$.
- Prove that the above grammar is ambiguous.
- Prove that any grammar that uses $B$ is ambiguous.
- If it is not specified, then "begin" and "end" words are just some terminals (those are lower-case after all).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: it will just produce "b;b" or "b;b;b;b" ... I'm not sure how to prove that ambiguous, still confusing about this problem

Comment: @Herious Do you know how to produce "b;b;b"? In how many ways you can do this?

Comment: @Herious Take $C \to \mathtt{b}\, B\, \mathtt{b}$. In how many ways you can get "bb;b;bb"? What about $D \to \mathtt{begin}\, B\, \mathtt{end}$?

Comment: oh my bad, I get it now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

begin and end must be terminals.

all CFG (without useless symbols) with left and right recursion for the same symbol is ambiguous.

In this case, the productions A -> A ; A | a | S are causing ambiguity.

For example, the string 'begin a; a; a end' has 2 leftmost derivations:

1. S > begin A end > begin A ; A end > begin A ; A; A end > begin a ; A ; A end >
   begin a ; a ; A end > begin a ; a ; a end
2. S > begin A end > begin A ; A end > begin a ; A end > begin a ; A ; A end >
   begin a ; a ; A end > begin a ; a ; a end

This is because the production A -> A ; A  does not indicate whether the ";" is left or rigth associative. If you want ";" to be left associative, you should write:

A -> A ; a | A ; S | a | S

I hope this help you.